# How to do return View () access Register Account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two buttons in the index.
I'm a Customer Button
I'm a Salesperson button

These buttons will access different ActionResult so that they can activate TempData with values corresponding to the button that was clicked.

Example:
I'm a customer for ActionResult Customer
I'm an Advertiser for ActionResult Advertiser

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Customer()
    {
        TempData["ocorrencia"] = "Customer";
        return View("Register", Account);//Accuses error
    }

    public ActionResult Advertiser()
    {
        TempData["ocorrencia"] = "Advertiser";
        return View("Register", "Account");//Accuses error
    }
}
```

If you use this statement, you acknowledge error **return View("Register", "Account");**

How to make return view register account access?

Comment: What error are you getting when using `return View("Register", "Account");`?

Comment: Server Error in Application '/'.
The 'Register' view or its master was not found or no display engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~ / Views / Home / Register.aspx
~ / Views / Home / Register.ascx

Comment: With the code you shared the razor view engine is going to load the view from `~/Shared/Views/Register.cshtml` or `~/Views/Account/Register.cshtml`.  Where are you getting the `Home` part in this ? Are you having custom code to override the default view location ?

Comment: Friend I got with this return RedirectToAction ("Register", "Account");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solve your issue is in this statement:

> These buttons will access different ActionResult

Since it implies you want redirect to another action method, it is necessary to return `RedirectToAction` instead of `ViewResult`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
```

Your attempt to `return View("Register", "Account");` returns error because the `Register` view is exist in different folder named `Account` (it must be in the same folder as controller class name prefix to call directly by its name, i.e. `Home`).